# WPF Binding ComboBox в DataGrid.ColumnHeader

Tags: c#, wpf

В заголовке столбца используется ComboBox.

Как привязать свойство ComboBox.SelectedIndex к полю в ViewModel?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxColumn1" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource SourceGridHeader}" />
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: мне кажется, что идти тем путем, который вы описываете неправильно. Наверно лучше будет для каждого столбца отдельно описывать привязку для заголовков.

Comment: Это переписал, но всё равно свойство не привязывается.

Comment: Нет. Кажется побывал уже всё.

Comment: ...если у вас не работет - значит вы что-то не так делаете, покажите свой код для начала

Comment: Что я только не побывал. Просто "public int SelectedIndex=0;" и класс с INotifyPropertyChanged и ObservableCollection.

Comment: ...покажите ваш код

Comment: Получилось только задать значение в ComboBox из ModelView. Это не требуется. Нужно получить выбранное значение всех ComboBox`ов. Это буду делать через команды или обратившись к ним на прямую.

Comment: для значения привязывайте не `SelectedIndex` а `SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы привязка работала, вам нужно правильно указать путь

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource SourceGridHeader}" 
              SelectedIndex="{Binding DataContext.SelectedIndex, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```